# Moodle 2.5 file picker issue

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 2.5.4 (Build: 20140113) and its fresh installs. The file picker drag and drop is not working properly. It throws [[ServerConnection: Error]] and Invalid JSON string error. This error occurs both drag and drop the file into the LMS and Add-> upload file.

System configuration: `windows 7, PHP version 5.2.0, MySQL version 5.5, Apache 2.4.7`

Anything needs be done to resolve this issue. I am using XAMPP server version 1.8.1 and am using an essential theme for my LMS. Also, please let me know how to add my own banner on top of the theme?

Answer (score 0):

Please see your PHP version minimum requirement for moodle 2.5 is 5.3.3.

- See requirement http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_2.5_release_notes
- Try disabling your theme and try Moodle standard theme to drag and
  upload.
- Check for Ajax in your site adminstration.
- Browser you are using? As Drag and drop is not supported in IE8.
- For adding theme see this post may help you
  https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=84466

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the 'real' error message being returned from the server.

- The first step to doing this involves turning on debugging on your
  server ( http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging ).
- Next you need to open    up the developer tools for your browser (the exact way of doing this    will vary depending on the web browser you are using).
- Now go to the 'network' section of the developer tools, before triggering the error
  message (either by drag + drop or by 'add file').
- Look for a new entry added to the network section of the developer tools - if you
  click on this new entry, you should be able to view the full error
  message.

Once you have that full error message, you can post it here and that should make it easier to figure out the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server configuration for example in Nginx.conf, all you need to do is to alter this line:

```
client_max_body_size [limit]M
```

inside the server section, where limit in this case is the size (in megabytes) that you want to allow.